# Alexa Smart Home Skill multiple BrightnessController interface instances

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

If I want to develop an Alexa Smart Home Skill for a device (single endpoint) which has two different dimmable lights, what is the right way to model it?

It looks like the [`Alexa.BrightnessController`](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-brightnesscontroller.html) interface does not support multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple instances are not available for specific controllers like in your case, the more specific the controller, the more natural the utterances are for your users.

That being said, the generic controllers provide some benefits not available with more specific controllers, such as the ability to implement multiple instances of a controller for a single device, and support for semantics.

Generic controller interfaces are general-purpose interfaces that you can use to model different components of a smart home device in your Alexa skills.

More information about the Generic Controllers: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/generic-controllers.html